# Ubuntu Hangs on Started update UTMP abount system changes

Tags: 18.04, vmware, macbook-pro, vmware-fusion

Running Ubuntu on MAC book pro in VMware Fusion 8.5

Ubuntu Hangs on Started update UTMP about system changes.

I Have restarted system with same results

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem today. Most of the answers I found dealt with Nvidia card problems, but for me it was simply caused by running out of space on my root filesystem. Get to a command prompt or kernel virtual terminal (Ctrl-Alt-F3 should do it) and check your disk space with `df`. Then just `rm` some files till you have a reasonable amount of free space and reboot, and you should be OK.